# Eigen: Map real and imag MatrixXd to MatrixXcd

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am working with some large data set where the real and imag part of a complex matrix is stored separately in a file, and I would like to create a Eigen::MatrixXcd from such data:

```
   // read data, note that real and imag data are stored separately
   // and the file reader API only allow read them in continuous fashion. 
   MatrixXd buf(nrow, ncol * 2);
   get_realpart_from_file(buf.data(), nrow * ncol);
   get_imagpart_from_file(buf.data() + nrow * ncol, nrow * ncol);
   // the above takes about 4 sec for a ~2 GB data block.
   // now we have buf contains [<real data> ... <imag data>]
   // but we would like access the data as complex matrix
   ???? what to do there?
```

The naive way would be to copy the data like the follows:

```
   MatrixXd data;
   data = buf.block(0, 0, nrow, ncol) + buf.block(0, ncol, nrow, ncol) * std::complex<double>(0, 1);
```

but this took 22 second for that 2GB data block.

I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this, that is similar to:

```
   Map<MatrixXcd, {some magic}> data(buf.data(), {some magic});
   // use data like a complex matrix
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The data needs to be copied anyway because `MatrixXcd` is expected interleaved real/complex entries. Nonetheless you can avoid the costly complex product with:

```
MatrixXcd data(nrow,ncol);
data.real() = buf.leftCols(ncol);
data.imag() = buf.rightCols(ncol);
```

Also makes sure to benchmark with compiler optimizations ON, 22s for your initial version seems to be too much.